# How to get xAxis correct on LineChart?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to display a LineChart in Recharts where the data is numeric and the xAxis is also numeric but it is implicit (not explicitly stored in the data).

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0r7oepyn/1/) illustrates the issue.

If I change the `<XAxis />` to `<XAxis type="numeric" />`, it still doesn't display correctly, in fact the lines are not drawn at all (but the tooltip is there). Similarly adding the domain to the XAxis does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's just a misunderstanding here. I don't see numeric as a type property in the documentation, but I do see `number` as a property. http://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis#type